# Add program to startup linux server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, boot, reboot

Hello,

I have a Ubuntu Linux server (14.04) and i'd like to add NzbGet to the startup programs. 
NzbGet Wiki tells me this :

> Starting on boot
>
> NZBGet can run in background as daemon (service). When starting NZBGet
>   use command -D instead of -s:
>
> /nzbget -D 
>  
>   You will not see any output of this
>   command. Add this line to the init scripts of your system. Also add a
>   shutdown line to the shutdown scripts:
>
> /nzbget -Q

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the script from [here](http://www.htpcguides.com/install-nzbget-stable-ubuntu-ppa/) or create one yourself using template `/etc/init.d/skeleton`. Also have a look at `/etc/init.d/README`.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to test the command (so /path/to/nzbget -D) and then add that to your personal crontab (I tend to use @reboot.) If this needs to run as root, you might want to run an upstart script.